# Grabbing a word and variable number of characters afterwards

Tags: regex, string, text, awk, sed

I have a `TAB` separated file containing long strings, which I intend to filter the `8th column` which has a mix of letters and characters randomly, to containing only "`;OCCURRENCE=some words|`" part as below:

input.txt

```
1 138440 CAMEL C T . . MANY-WORDS-AND-CHARACTERS(*/-;|\);OCCURRENCE=HOY-BR|MANY-WORDS-AnD-CHARACTeRS(;*/-|\)
1 138440 CAT CD TGGD . . MANY-WORDS-AND-CHARACTERS(;*/-|\);OCCURRENCE=DISC-BF5R|MANY-WORDS-AnD-CHARACTeRS(*/-|\;)
```

expected-output.txt:

```
1 138440 CAMEL C T . . ;OCCURRENCE=HOY-BR|
1 138440 CAT CD TGGD . . ;OCCURRENCE=DISC-BF5R|
```

I tried to "clean" the `8th column` until the semi-column with `OCCUR` string shows up with `sed 's/.*;OCCUR//g'` but it erases other columns, so it did not work.

How can I keep the `;OCCURANCE=whatever-word|` pattern in 8th column without erasing the other columns?

Comment: You say it's tab separated, but the sample data you showed don't have `\t` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For GNU sed, and to be exact:

```
$ sed -E 's/((\S+\s){7}).*(\;OCCURRENCE=[^\|]*\|).*/\1\3/' input.txt
1 138440 CAMEL C T . . ;OCCURRENCE=HOY-BR|
1 138440 CAT CD TGGD . . ;OCCURRENCE=DISC-BF5R|
```

So no matter it's `TAB` or space separated, filter the 8th column according to your description.

`\S` means a Non-whitespace character.
`\s` means a Whitespace character.
`+` means the character/group appear one or more times.
`{7}` means the character/group appear 7 times.
`[^\|]` means any character that is not a `|`.
`\num` means `num`th `()` catched contents.

Check [Regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) for more.

Comment: Can you explain it a bit?

Comment: @bapors Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'match($NF,/\;[a-zA-Z]+[^|]*/){$NF=substr($NF,RSTART,RLENGTH+1)} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code here.

```
awk '                                   ##Starting awk program here.
match($NF,/\;[a-zA-Z]+[^|]*/){          ##Using match function here to match a REGEX in $NF(last field of line).
  $NF=substr($NF,RSTART,RLENGTH+1)      ##Re-assigning last field and keeping its value as substring values of RSTART and RLENGTH
}                                       ##Where RSTART and RLENGTH variables will be SET when a match is found within match REGEX, refer man awk for more details too.
1                                       ##Mentioning 1 will print edited/non-edited current line.
'  Input_file                           ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Perl

```
perl -lne ' while(/(\S+)/g) { $x++; if ($x==8) { $y=$1; @y=split(/;|\|/,$y); $z=quotemeta($y); s/$z/;$y[3]|/g;  } } ; print;  $x=0 '
```

using inputs

```
$ cat bapors.txt
1 138440 CAMEL C T . . MANY-WORDS-AND-CHARACTERS(*/-;|\);OCCURRENCE=HOY-BR|MANY-WORDS-AnD-CHARACTeRS(;*/-|\)
1 138440 CAT CD TGGD . . MANY-WORDS-AND-CHARACTERS(;*/-|\);OCCURRENCE=DISC-BF5R|MANY-WORDS-AnD-CHARACTeRS(*/-|\;)

$ perl -lne ' while(/(\S+)/g) { $x++; if ($x==8) { $y=$1; @y=split(/;|\|/,$y); $z=quotemeta($y); s/$z/;$y[3]|/g;  } } ; print;  $x=0 ' bapors.txt
1 138440 CAMEL C T . . ;OCCURRENCE=HOY-BR|
1 138440 CAT CD TGGD . . ;OCCURRENCE=DISC-BF5R|

$
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/\S+/\n&/8;s/\n.*(;OCCURRENCE=[^|]*\|).*/\1/;s/\n//' file
```

Prepend a newline to the eighth field of a line and use it in a second substitution as marker. Remove the marker and characters before and after the matched string to be retained. Remove the newline should the second match not be successful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, sed -r for extended regular expressions:

```
sed -r 's/ \S+(;OCCUR[^|]+\|)\S+/ \1/g'
```

It cleans by extracting what you want to keep. It is not specific to the 8th column though.